# Login don't work on laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have working on a application that i don't develop. However i have basic knowledge on laravel. 
I have the application, and the login worked days ago till i edit the routes.php and stop working. 
Actually i verify the parameters (user, password), and they are right, the parameters are the same, but the login does not redirect me to the main page.

I put the LogController.php

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{
    if(Auth::attempt(['user' => $request['user'], 'password' => $request['password'], 'perfil' => 2]))
    {
        Dashboard::insertGetId(['user' => $request['user'], 'perfil' => '2']);
        return Redirect::to('administrator');

    }elseif (Auth::attempt(['user' => $request['user'], 'password' => $request['password'], 'perfil' => 1])) {
      # code...
       return Redirect::to('portal-empleado');
    }else {
      # code...
      Session::flash('error_message', $request['password']); 
      return Redirect::to('login');
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout']); //Finalizar sesion
Route::resource('login','LogController');
Route::get('/', function (){return view('content');});
Route::get('Quienes-Somos',['uses' => 'HomeController@qs_index','as'=> 'Who_we_are']);
Route::get('Normatividad',['uses' => 'HomeController@n_index','as'=> 'regulations']);
Route::get('Servicios',['uses' => 'HomeController@s_index','as'=> 'services']);
Route::POST('Contacto',['uses' => 'ContactController@store','as'=> 'contact']);

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function ()
{
    Route::get('portal-empleado',['uses' => 'EmployeeController@index','as'=> 'portal-empleado']);
    Route::get('nomina_index', 'PayrollController@view_date_generation_payroll');
    Route::POST('nomina', 'PayrollController@store');
    Route::get('pdfPayroll', 'PayrollController@pdfPayroll');
    Route::get('seguridad_social', function (){return view('modules.employee.social_security_certificate.index');});
    Route::get('certificado', 'WorkcertificateController@Contract');
    Route::resource('curriculum_vitae','CurriculumController');
    Route::resource('contractregistre','ContractregistreController');
    Route::get('administrator', function (){return view('administrator.dashboard');});
    Route::get('view_certificate', function (){return  view('administrator.view.viewcertificate');});
    Route::get('view_payroll', function (){return  view('administrator.view.viewpayroll');});
    Route::resource('administrator','DashboardController');
    Route::get('viewcertificate', 'WorkcertificateController@viewcertificate');
    Route::get('editviewcertificate/{value}',['as' => 'editviewcertificate','uses' => 'WorkcertificateController@editviewcertificate']);
    Route::get('viewpayroll', 'PayrollController@viewpayroll');
    Route::get('FilterviewPayroll/{value}',['as' => 'FilterviewPayroll','uses' => 'PayrollController@FilterviewPayroll']);
    //Route::get('help', function (){return view('components.help.index');});
    //Route::get('Instrucciones', function(){return view('components.help.index');});
    Route::get('portal', function(){return view('modules.services.portal');});
    Route::get('view_Contract', 'WorkcertificateController@Contract');
});
/* Imports*/

Route::get('import_contracts', 'ImportController@index_contracts');
Route::post('cargar_datos_contratos', 'ImportController@cargar_datos_contratos');
Route::get('import_payrolls', 'ImportController@index_payrolls');
Route::post('cargar_datos_payrolls', 'ImportController@cargar_datos_payrolls');

Route::get("user_mig", function()
{
    temporalestla\User::truncate();
    set_time_limit(3200);
    $contr = temporalestla\ContractUser::all();
    foreach ($contr as $value)
    {
        $psw = \Hash::make($value->id_employee);
        $user = new temporalestla\User
        ([
            "full_name"=>$value->name_used,
            "user" => $value->id_employee,
            "password" => $psw,
            "perfil" => 1
        ]);
        //dd($user);
        $user->save();
    }
    return "Proceso finalizado.";
});
```

And the RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{

    protected $auth;


    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->check()) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

If someone could help me i'll be eternally grateful.

Comment: What exactly did you change in `routes.php`, it is probably the best place to start looking

Comment: What's going on with the `return mixed` in your `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware?

Comment: @Spholt , i just modify the code tab, i didn't change any line as far as i remember

Comment: @RossWilson Wilson, actually, i don't know because i don't create the RedirectIfAuthenticated and i don't create the project, can you tell me what is it used for?

Comment: The middleware comes with Laravel. My point was your code should be throwing errors having `return mixed` where it is (well not just because of where it is, there are multiple reasons why it's wrong).

Comment: @RossWilson, so, you said that there no explanation for having there the return mixed?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be there. First and foremost, it's a return statement that is outside of a method so it should be causing a `Parse error`.

Comment: Please add answers below in the answer section, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The error that i have was a database error. However, I had a parse error in my RedirectIfAuthenticated where there was a return mixed, it's fixed now, thanks to all of you.